# How to create a .jar file in a custom gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jar, gradle-plugin

So at the moment I'm trying to create a custom gradle project.
I want to create the jar (it's a kotlin project) and then get a reference to the jar and all the dependencies of that jar.

I've already done this in a custom maven plugin where it looks like that:

```
@Mojo(name = "custom-plugin", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_RESOURCES, requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE_PLUS_RUNTIME)
class CustomMavenMojo : AbstractMojo() {
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "\${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private val mavenProject: MavenProject? = null

    @Throws(MojoExecutionException::class, MojoFailureException::class)
    override fun execute() {
        val targetFolder = File(mavenProject.model.build.directory) // the build folder
        val jarFile = mavenProject.artifact.file // This is the build jar file
        val dependencies = mavenProject.artifacts // The jar's dependencies
    }
}
```

So as I can grasp it, in gradle i would have to to this a bit different.
I guess I would have to call the jar plugin/task to create the jar, thats where it starts getting a bit fuzzy. I saw one can call a plugin, but which is the right one and how would i then access the created jar? In addition I would love to geht the dependencies.

Heres what I got so far:

```
class CustomGradlePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.task("custom-jar-task") {
            project.plugins.apply('???') // which plugin do i call here to create the .jar file?
            val createdJar = ... // and how do i get the created jar file?

            project.configurations.forEach { configuration ->
                configuration.dependencies.forEach { dependency ->
                    val dependencyJarFile = ... // how would i get the depencenies jar file here?

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as i can tell, I've solved it on a basic level.

What I found was that one can depend on another task, in this case I depend on the jar task - This way the jar task is executed before. After this I just get the created jar through the jar task and then get the dependencies through the runtime configuration.

There are some things which to note here. First one might apply the java-plugin or org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm plugin inside the custom plugin, i guess these would affect the created jar? Also I'm not quite sure how configurations of the jar task would affect this, but i guess they are just applied before and one gets the finished jar eitherway.
Also clearly this targets the jar created by the jar task, to target some other jar (custom fatJar or something like that), one would have to change the task accordingly.

```
class CustomGradlePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.task("custom-jar-task") {
            // First depend on jar task to make sure the .jar file is build
            it.dependsOn(
                project.tasks.getByName("jar")
            )

            it.doLast {
                // Get the jar task
                val jarTask = project.tasks.getByName("jar") as Jar
                // Get the .jar file through the jar task
                val jarFile = jarTask.archiveFile.orNull

                println("Build Jar: ${jarFile?.asFile?.name}")

                println("Runtime dependencies:")
                // Get the runtime configuration resolve it and iterate over all dependencies.
                project.configurations.getByName("runtime").resolve().forEach {
                    println("-- ${it.name}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```